Artist puzzle/ARG: "The key is: 33.60d813551512431"
A Greek singer/trapper has a website with his name on it that's very cryptic. I'm linking the website here https://sinboy.gr . There are a few things that are strange but I would like to focus on the main page after the flashing letters and images. The site says: "The key is:
33.60d813551512431". Can anybody identify this string of characters? Is it a cipher or something else?
I also tried snooping around the source code and at the very bottom of it I found some phrases in Latin which Google Translate wasn't able to translate very well.

The "phrases in Latin" is just Lorem Ipsum with the words "SInBoY" and "SIn BoY" scattered in between.  Maybe there's something encoded in the number of words between each instance of his name, but the text itself is bog-standard.
